# Dynamics crm on premise installatiom

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365-v9

Can I have two separate installations(different server/different Database) using/sharing the same OU in active directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same OU for multiple installations.

Each installation will have a unique guid on the end of each object, but it can get messy after awhile.

We would always create a separate OU for each but it isn't necessary.
[image: AD Example1]

Answer (score 0):

Yes
Dynamics is scalable.

There are multiple server roles , and you can install each of them n scalable manner on multiple servers , pointing to the same deployment database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/deploy/install-dynamics-365-front-back-end-server-roles